# Office 365 add-in outlook get AAD token to Call WebAPI

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365-apps

Now that I'm developing the Office 365 outlook add-in, I need call WebAPI in the Office 365 add-in, and WebAPI is protected by AAD. To ask, how do I get AAD token from the Office 365 add-in and can be used in both browser and outlook application?

Answer (score 0):

No matter the office add-in is for the Office desktop or online version, the office add-in is a web app.

There are two usual flows we can authenticate in a web app, one is implicit flow and the other is authorization Code flow. Here is the difference between these two flows:

> Implicit flow: Communication between the add-in and the online service is implemented with client-side JavaScript.
>
> Authorization Code flow: Communication is server-to-server between your add-in's web application and the online service. So, it is implemented with server-side code.

And more detail about the authentication/authorization you can refer the
document below:

[Authorize external services in your Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins)